# Accessing Different Middleware Data

Tags: node.js

Hello I have a question can we access middleware data from another middleware
Example:
Like I have a First Middleware and i want to access that middleware data from second middleware.

```
    app.use('/firstMiddleware', (req,res,next))=>{
    const a= 5;
    }

    app.use('/secondMiddleware', (req,res,next))=>{
    //Can i access first middleware variable here and print it out?
    console.log(a)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern is to put the shared data in either the `req` or `res` object, depending on the purpose of the data.

For example, some authentication middleware adds `req.user`:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // authenticate user
  ...
  req.user = {...};
  next();
});
```

Or, for example, a middleware which provides variables for rendering a template:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // do some operation
  ...
  res.locals.something = {...};
  next();
});
```

(See more about [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals).)

You can then use this in any following route or middleware:

```js
app.get('/some/path', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  console.log(res.locals.something);
});
```

Watch out though – the order of middleware matters.

Read more in [Writing Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).